# One column condition in sql

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table:

```
[letter] [Name]  [status]  [price]
      A    row1       1        11
      A    row1       1        15
      B    row2       2         9
      B    row2       3        23
      B    row2       3        30
```

And want to select data something like this:

```
 SELECT letter, Name, 
    COUNT(*),
    CASE WHEN price>10 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE NULL END
    GROUP BY letter, Name
```

the result is:

```
 A    row1     2      2 
 B    row2     1      null 
 B    row2     2      2
```

But I want this format:

```
 A    row1      2     2 
 B    row2      3     2
```

Please, help me to modify my query

Comment: I doubt your example. When you group by letter and name and there are just two such combinations, you can only get two rows, not three.

Comment: Is it MySQL you are using? Just to explain your mistake: What you do is look per letter and name at one of their prices (randomly). If this price happens to be greater than 10 then you show the number of records for that letter and name, otherwise you show null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close. Probably want this instead:

```
SELECT letter, Name, 
  COUNT(*),
  SUM(CASE WHEN price>10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM TableThatShouldHaveAppearedInTheQuestionInTheFromClause
GROUP BY letter, Name
```

should work. Assuming that the intention of the fourth column is to return the count of the number of rows, within each group, with a `price` greater than `10`. It's also possible to do this as a `COUNT()` over a `CASE` then returns non-`NULL` and `NULL` results for the rows that should and should not be counted, but I find the above form easier to quickly reason about.

Answer (score 1):

Since nulls are not used in aggregate functions:

```
SELECT letter
     , name
     , count(*)
     , count(
         case when price > 10 then 1 
         end
       ) 
  FROM t
 GROUP BY letter, name
```

You were very close.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the other answers, probably this is not the best way, but it will work.
The count of the prices over 10 is made with a subquery which has a condition on `price > 10` and which is joined to the current `TAB` record with the alias `A` for the same `letter` and `name`.

```
SELECT letter, 
       Name, 
       COUNT(*),
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TAB WHERE letter = A.letter and Name = A.Name WHERE price>10)
FROM TAB A
GROUP BY letter, Name
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Hatem, in what way is this not an answer?

Comment: You may explain more, putting the query as it is won't help the others the understands the origin of the problem. for example: see the correct answer.